# Como criar um objeto com class template?

Tags: c++, herança, c++11, template

Tenho este código:

Main.cpp

```
Warehouse<Base<int>> arm(1, 1, 1, 1);
arm.createSubBase(1,1,1);
```

Warehouse.h

```
private:
 vector<Base<T>*> whouse;
public :
 void createSubBase(int, int, int);

template <class T> 
void Warehouse<T>::createSubBase(int,int,int) {
  Base<T>* dN = new SubBase<T>(int,int,int,int); ***<-ERROR MESSAGE:" in file included from"***
     whouse.push_back(dN);
}
```

Base.h

```
template <class T>
class Base {
private:
 int I,a,b,c;
public :
  Base(int,int,int,int);
}

template <class T>
Base<T>::Base(int i, int a, int b, int c) {
    this -> I = i;
    this -> a= a;
    this -> b= b;
    this -> c = c;
}
```

SubBase.h

```
template <class T>
class SubBase: public Base<T> {
public:
  SubBase(int, int, int,int);
}
template <class T>
SubBase<T>::SubBase(int, int, int , int) : Depositos<T>(int,int,int,int) {...}
```

Alguém sabe porque me esta a dar aquela mensagem de erro? É que dá me essa mensagem e dá me erro no include do vector.

Não entendo porque não me deixa criar este objeto:

```
Base < T > * b = new subbase < T > ( int , int , int );
```

Comment: C++ exercendo sua profissão com orgulho e feiura.

Comment: Por favor, coloque a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: Assumindo que você está chamando "Base < T > * b = new subbase < T > ( int , int , int );" dentro de main, qual é o tipo de T ?

Comment: A mensagem de erro é muito maior que essa que você mandou. Sugiro você copiar tudo, inclusive o código (que do jeito que você fez, não consigo tentar compilar aqui).

Answer (score 4):

Tem tanto erro no seu código que é difícil saber por onde começar.

Primeiro de tudo é que você não colocou o código original, e nem a mensagem de erro original. Quando você editou o código para colocá-lo aqui, provavelmente inseriu um monte de outros erros. Daí eu não sei se os erros que eu vejo são os originais ou os inseridos na edição. Por exemplo, muito provavelmente você renomeou sua classe `Depositos` para `Base` ao postar, mas esqueceu de atualizar o construtor de `SubBase`, mas não dá para ter certeza de onde veio esse `Depositos` sem ver o código original.

Dito isto, seu uso de templates não faz o menor sentido, pois hora nenhuma você usa ou instancia variáveis do tipo T. Você por acaso não queria declarar a sua classe `Base` como sendo o seguinte?

```
template <class T>
class Base {
private:
 T I,a,b,c;
public :
  Base(T, T, T, T);
};
```

Daí faz mais sentido usar um template, mas precisaria de mudar mais coisas para funcionar... de qualquer modo, peguei os pedaços de código que você postou, juntei tudo em um único arquivo, e fui modificando até compilar. Ficou assim:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Base {
private:
 int I,a,b,c;
public :
  Base(int,int,int,int);
};

template <class T>
Base<T>::Base(int i, int a, int b, int c) {
    this -> I = i;
    this -> a= a;
    this -> b= b;
    this -> c = c;
}

template <class T>
class SubBase: public Base<T> {
public:
  SubBase(int, int, int,int);
};

template <class T>
SubBase<T>::SubBase(int i, int a, int b, int c):
    Base<T>(i,a,b,c)
{
}

template <class T>
class Warehouse {
private:
 vector<Base<T>*> whouse;
public :
 void createSubBase(int, int, int);
};

template <class T> 
void Warehouse<T>::createSubBase(int A, int B, int C) {
  Base<T>* dN = new SubBase<T>(A, B, C, 42);
  whouse.push_back(dN);
}

int main()
{
  Warehouse<Base<int>> arm;
  arm.createSubBase(1,1,1);
}
```

O primeiro problema que eu notei foi que você esqueceu o ponto-e-vírgula `;` no final declaração das classes. A função específica que você apontou como estando errada, era assim:

```
template <class T>
void Warehouse<T>::createSubBase(int,int,int) {
   Base<T>* dN = new SubBase<T>(int,int,int,int);
   whouse.push_back(dN);
}
```

e na minha versão ficou assim:

```
template <class T> 
void Warehouse<T>::createSubBase(int A, int B, int C) {
  Base<T>* dN = new SubBase<T>(A, B, C, 42);
  whouse.push_back(dN);
}
```

Basicamente, você estava chamando o construtor que pega 4 `int`s, mas não estava passando nenhum valor para eles. Na minha versão, eu passo os mesmos parâmetros que a função `createSubBase` recebe, mais 42 como último parâmetro.

Você fez mesma coisa nessa linha aqui:

```
SubBase<T>::SubBase(int, int, int , int) : Depositos<T>(int,int,int,int) {...}
```

ou seja, em vez de passar os parâmetros devidos, escreveu `int` no lugar de cada um deles (sem contar que escreveu `Depositos` em vez de `Base`). O meu equivalente ficou assim:

```
SubBase<T>::SubBase(int i, int a, int b, int c): Base<T>(i,a,b,c) {}
```

ou seja, a função não faz nada, mas compila (a sua tinha reticências no lugar do conteúdo, isso com certeza não compila, mas é certamente uma edição sua antes de postar).

Finalmente, você marcou a questão com a tag "C++11" e, de fato, usou uma funcionalidade do C++11, ou seja, uma funcionalidade que só foi incluída na versão do C++ publicada em 2011, que é:

```
Warehouse<Base<int>> arm;
```

na versão anterior do C++, este código é inválido, e deveria ter um espaço entre os dois sinais de `>`:

```
Warehouse<Base<int> > arm;
```

Eu mantive essa particularidade na minha versão do código, portanto, para compilar tive que usar o seguinte comando (usando o compilador [Clang](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang)):

$ clang++ -std=c++11 -o warehouse warehouse.cpp

ou, no compilador do [GNU](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection):

$ g++ -std=c++11 -o warehouse warehouse.cpp

Este comando `-std=c++11` só se faz necessário por você não dar espaço entre os dois `>` no final da instanciação do template.

Bem, isso tudo foram só os erros de compilação, pois o seu código tem ainda erros conceituais, más práticas e ao menos 2 bugs.

Como já disse, você não usa o valor do template para nada. E justamente por isso o código compila. O `Warehouse` instanciado na seguinte linha:

```
`Warehouse<Base<int>> arm;`
```

vai ter o seu tipo `T = Base<int>`, portanto o `vector` interno a ele será do tipo:

```
vector<Base<Base<int>>*> whouse; // Simplesmente substitui T pelo tipo Base<int>
```

Você provavelmente queria:

```
vector<Base<int>*> whouse;
```

e portanto deveria ter instanciado como:

```
Warehouse<int> arm;
```

Mas como eu disse, do jeito que está compila, porque no final das contas, lá dentro de `Base`, o tipo T não é usado para nada.

Um bug é que você chama `new` e aloca memória, mas não chama o `delete` em lugar nenhum. Você devia implementar o destrutor da sua classe, e chamar `delete` para todos os elementos do seu vetor `whouse`, deixar de fazê-lo acarreta um problema chamado vazamento de memória.

A má prática é que você não tem nada a ganhar (exceto o bug de vazamento de memória) ao gerenciar ponteiros explicitamente com `new` e `delete`. No seu caso, me parece muito melhor usar um ponteiro inteligente, que gerencia a memória automaticamente para você, como o `std::shared_ptr` ou o `std::unique_ptr` (ambos só disponíveis no C++11).

O outro bug é que seu destrutor de `Base` deveria ser virtual, senão o objeto não é corretamente destruído (nem se você chamar `delete`, nem se você seguir minha sugestão de usar um ponteiro inteligente). No seu caso, como você instancia subclasses (`SubBase`) e armazena em ponteiros para a classe pai (`Base`), você precisaria necessariamente declarar o destrutor de Base como sendo `virtual`:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
private:
 int I,a,b,c;
public :
  Base(int,int,int,int);
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
```